# Why is one screw in V-brake a lot tighter?

Tags: brakes, maintenance

I noticed that whenever tuning my V-brakes, I always have to tighten one of the screws a lot more than the one on the other side. I was wondering why this is the case. Of course this means the spring on one side is working a lot more than the other one. This difference seems to get larger very slowly.

I even bought a used bike a few years ago and the brakes were so bad I actually had to use holes in different positions to install the V-brakes (one in the middle, one in the bottom). Worked well enough, though...

So is there anything I am doing wrong when tuning the brakes? Is there a problem if I change one of the screws by a longer one if necessary?

I usually leave one screw untightened and just tighten the other one as necessary, to minimize tension.

[image: photo taken from the bottom of the bike]

[image: no description]

Comment: have you tried thoroughly cleaning the pivot point and other internals of the v-brake arm? Does spraying wd-40 or a similar product help at all? Is your wheel properly dished? Is your wheel properly centered on your axle?

Comment: It's fairly common for the two arms to be fairly far out of balance, in terms of the screw tension.  I've never sussed out all the causes for this, though differences in friction are definitely a part of it.  (Oh, and be aware that often there are several settings (notches) for the spring, and the two may not have the same setting.)

Comment: @Maarten-Monicaforpresident Yes, the wheels are dished, trued and centered. I have not tried cleaning the brakes thoroughly, which I will certainly do and come back with the results. Thank you!

Comment: Is your front brake working correctly and as-expected?  Do you ride on salty roads at all?  The rear of the bike suffers more from road salt and general detris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessarily a problem when there's disparity between the centering screws. The whole reason they exist is to be able to adjust the springs to different amounts of tension to compensate for asymmetry or imprecision in the brake posts, the springs, the brake arm forgings, etc. If one arm is overtly sticky or rough when you disengage the spring then you address that by cleaning and lubricating it, but don't worry about it otherwise.

Sometimes this is also caused by one screw missing the stub of spring entirely because of wear or imprecision in the spring carrier assembly, which usually results in that spring having no preload despite the screw being threaded in some amount, and then the other one will usually have to be nearly all the way out. Sometimes this is fixable, but sometimes not.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the brake arm with the tighter screw needs a good cleaning of its internals. Try spraying some penetrating fluid like wd-40 in between the brake arm and the pivot and see if that helps at all. If cleaning (thoroughly, when taken apart) doesn't solve the issue I can think of a few alternative reasons your brake arm might not be properly moving:

- The cable and housing can pull the brake arms to one side (adjust cable routing)
  (suggested by @Argenti Apparatus in the comments)
- Mount bolt too tight on 1 side
- Spring incorrectly installed (unlikely)
- one of the o-rings seen in the diagram below is incorrectly installed/seated

Are you sure your rim is properly centered in between the two brake arms? If not your wheel might need dishing or it might need to be centered on it's axle.

[image]

Comment: I've found that the cable and housing can pull the brake arms to one side also

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Good suggestion. If you're OK with it I'll add it to my answer (giving you the credit obv). If not that's perfectly fine too :)

Comment: Thats fine, go ahead

Answer (score 2):

Springs get old and loose their "sproing" over time, and not necessarily at the same rate.  Replacement springs may be available, but its generally less faff to replace the whole lot.

Most new aftermarket V brakes come as a set of two arms, brake pads, and springs.  You may or may not get bolts for your frame bosses, and generally you won't get a noodle.  And be mindful of the difference between V brakes and Mini V Brakes, which may not suit your levers.  Get the same length arms as your existing ones.

And if you're going that far, its pragmatic to replace the inner and outer cable at the same time.  There's no reason to change your brake lever assuming its working okay.

When you fit new arms, give the frame bosses a good clean, and a light/gentle polish with some emery paper to clean any dings.  Also ensure the boss studs are not loose in the frame, and are parallel with each other.